# is it true that whether a POS can read an NFC card, that POS is compatible with HCE?

Tags: nfc, security, card

I was wondering if the host card emulation would produce the same result as an physical contactless card is producing.

Comment: "POS"= "piece of sh..?"

Comment: @JRE, POS = Point Of Sale device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the general idea. HCE requires being able to emulate the same radio and data standards that the card reader expects. If for example the HCE device can do MiFare V1 and the reader can read MiFare V1  then it will work.